# Eclipse: how to add a default encoding to a eclipse xml settings file?

Tags: eclipse, encoding

My team is using the [Google Style Guide configurations for Eclipse](https://github.com/HPI-Information-Systems/Metanome/wiki/Installing-the-google-styleguide-settings-in-intellij-and-eclipse).

Is it possible to add a default encoding of UTF-8 to this settings file? If so, to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. The Google file is a code formatter style which does not include the file encoding settings for files.